# How can I get NT authority/system in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I installed an SQL server using the login NT authority/system and now I need in C# to retrieve that value as a string. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: @Aliostad would that actually work? I tried other stuff, but I didn't think of this very obvious answer. I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name //WorkstationId

Environment.MachineName.ToString(); //UserId
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, apart from my little joke :) for accessing service information, you would use [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class but unfortunately that will not work since that information is not exposed.

Your choice is to read the registry and open the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS2008` or any other sql service you have and then read the `ObjectName` entry.

For reading registry, have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx).